# Which Airflow permissions allow triggering of a DAG Run through the API?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

Using Airflow 2.0.2, I'm trying to use the airflow API to trigger DAG Runs. When I run a simple GET like

```sh
curl -X GET --user "fooUser:passw0rd" "${ENDPOINT_URL}/api/v1/pools"
```

I get expected results:

```json
{
  "pools": [
    {
      "name": "default_pool",
      "occupied_slots": 0,
      "open_slots": 128,
      "queued_slots": 0,
      "running_slots": 0,
      "slots": 128
    }
  ],
  "total_entries": 1
```

So the user `fooUser` does have some basic access to the API. But, trying to run

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}' --user "fooUser:passw0rd" "${ENDPOINT_URL}/api/v1/dags/myDag/dagRuns"
```

I get

```json
{
  "detail": null,
  "status": 403,
  "title": "Forbidden",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/PermissionDenied"
}
```

If I grant user `fooUser` the `Admin` role and use the same `curl` command, I successfully get

```json
{
  "conf": {},
  "dag_id": "myDag",
  "dag_run_id": "manual__2021-12-13T21:37:42.959274+00:00",
  "end_date": null,
  "execution_date": "2021-12-13T21:37:42.959274+00:00",
  "external_trigger": true,
  "start_date": "2021-12-13T21:37:42.964609+00:00",
  "state": "running"
}
```

I don't want this user to have `Admin` permissions though. I want just enough to allow them to trigger DAG Runs using the API. But looking at the list of permissions granted to `Admin` I can't tell which my `fooUser` needs in order to accomplish this.

Which specific permission(s) does a user need in order to be allowed to trigger DAG Runs using the Airflow API?

Answer (score 0):

testing a little bit, I've come to these rules:

`[can create on DAG Runs, can edit on DAGs]`

These are just to TRIGGER a dag run. If you want to edit a dag run, you'll have too alter those permissions.

Airflow version 2.3.4

[UPDATE]
Here are all permissions needed for each resource:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html#dag-level-permissions

Comment: seems that you are missing the role on the response